# задача регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как задать рег. выражение, которое будет делить следующую строку: `<sth1><sth2><sth3>`
Мне нужно получить все данные, находящиеся в <>, я пробывал вот так `[<.+>]`, но оно берет и пустые строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь можно предложить несколько вариантов с использованием шаблона для регулярного выражения и потока совпадений `Stream<MatchResult>`, который возвращается из метода `Matcher::results()`

- попроще: `"<([^>]+)>` - одна группа внутри угловых скобок, содержащая 1 и более символов, не равных закрывающей угловой скобке:

```java
public static List<String> splitSimple(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^>]+)>");
    return pattern.matcher(str)
        .results()
        .map(mr -> mr.group(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
System.out.println(splitSimple("<sth1><><sth2><><sth3>"));
// -> [sth1, sth2, sth3]
```

- посложнее, используя lookahead `(?=>)`/lookbehind `(?<=<)` для обнаружения угловых скобок, *которые исключаются* из результата (тогда можно использовать ссылку на метод `MatchResult::group`)

```java
public static List<String> split(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>)");
    return pattern.matcher(str)
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

System.out.println(split("<sth1><><sth2><><sth3>"));
// -> [sth1, sth2, sth3]
```

---

Также можно исключить строки, содержащие только пробельные символы внутри угловых скобок при помощи negative lookahead `(?!\\s+)`:

```java
public static List<String> split(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=<)(?!\\s+)[^>]+(?=>)");
    return pattern.matcher(str)
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

System.out.println(split("<sth1><><sth2><  \t \r\n><sth3>"));
// -> [sth1, sth2, sth3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так, будет создан список с любыми символами кроме пробела и скобок, потом джойним элементы списка в строку.

```
public static String splitString(String text) {
  String[] list_of_strings = text.split("[<]|[><]|\\s");
  String result =  String.join("", list_of_strings);
     
  return result;
    }
System.out.println(splitString("<hgf1. 75576jhgjh, jhgjhg77><sadfasdf2341234 ewfqwefqwe 4365346><2412341234 0 weqfqwe 00--- 34525>"));
```

Результат:

```
hgf1.75576jhgjh,jhgjhg77sadfasdf2341234ewfqwefqwe436534624123412340weqfqwe00---34525
```